# Power steering noisy and hard to turn UNTIL engine warms up

Tags: power-steering

I have a 1991 Toyota Camry.

The Power steering is noisy and hard to turn steering wheel UNTIL engine warms up.  Then it is fine.  What's happening?  I have sucked old old fluid and put in new (Dextron II ATF per manufacturers specs) but wife says it still doing the above but not as bad.  Once engine warms up, steers like it came out of showroom.

The sound is the same noise anyone would hear when turning the steering wheel all the way to the stop. A chirping noise. Why would it be hard to turn the wheel and chirp with any movement of the wheel but then be perfectly fine after the engine gets to normal operating temp?

Comment: What kind of noise does it make? Does it sound like a belt squealing, or does it sound more like the pump is whining?

Comment: What's the model and year? At any rate, the most likely culprit is a bad power steering pump.

Comment: It's either the belt is worn out (squeals until warm up) or the pump is going bad, but would need more information before I'd lean one way or the other.

Comment: If it is an early 90's GM it has "morning sickness". A common symptom and complaint just before the steering rack fails completely.

Comment: @mikes ... If we only knew, lol.

Comment: Sorry guys, thought I told you.  it is a 1991 Toyota Camry.  The sound is the same noise anyone would hear when turning the steering wheel all the way to the stop.  A chirping noise.  Why would it be hard to turn the wheel and chirp with any movement of the wheel but then be perfectly fine after the engine gets to normal operating temp?

Comment: user4578 - I edited your post with the info from your comment - you have the privs to do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are in need of a new power steering pump. The fluid is not being pumped properly to the steering rack when it is "cold". Once it "warms up" it seems to get to the steering rack easier and makes everything work properly. Think of it in terms of thermo-hydraulics, the warmer the fluid, the easier it is pushed through the system.

Answer (score 2):

While it is impossible to confirm a diagnosis without seeing/hearing the vehicle in person, I would put money on this being a loose power steering belt.

When the engine, or more importantly, the power steering belt and pulleys are cold, they do not 'grip' as well. This causes the belt to slip on the pulleys creating a chirping/squealing noise and decreased assistance in turning the steering wheel. This sound also occurs when running the steering into the stop because the load on the pump increases dramatically, usually causing the belt to slip.

Once the belt/pulleys warm up they 'grip' better and don't slip, so no noise is generated and the pump can assist steering as designed.

I'm assuming this is a 4 cylinder (3sfe engine) Camry, since the 6 cylinders were rare in 1991. The power steering pump is turned by it's own separate belt, which is a pain to replace since all the other belts must come off first. If they're due for service, replace all of your belts or just tighten up the power steering belt a bit and the noise should go away.

Be weary of shops that want to replace the pump or steering rack. I have yet to see a P.S. pump that didn't die due to lack of fluid from a leak, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: You may want to mention over-tightening belts (ones which do not use a tensioner pulley) will cause damage as well, or at the very least aid in the deterioration of the pump overtime. Just something to be careful of, is all.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 2004 Honda Accord, which had the same issue, but I just fixed it. The issue of my vehicle is the power steer was hard to turn during the cold days when the vehicle was just started. Once the engine temperature increases to the normal level, the issue goes away.

I first changed the power steering fluid, but the problem was still there. Several days ago, I changed the o-ring from the power steering return line. After several days test (the temperature of these days were around 45 degrees in Fahrenheit), the problem went away completely. The o-ring costs about 3 bucks from the Honda dealer, and the job only needs a screwdriver, which takes about 10 minutes. I put the Youtube link, which I followed to do this job (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJkESNAVx20). Given the low cost and easy job, there is no harm to try. Hope it helps.